# Filter lightning list view using current user

Tags: lightning, list-view, filters

Is there a way to use a lightning view filter to only show records for the current user? This filter did not allow for the non-mobile

```
Reviewer Assigned equals $User.ID
```

results in '*The value $User.ID is only allowed in Mobile Configuration Filters*'

Some interesting discussions about this. Workaround for me would be to create a hard coded user name filter and clone the same view for multiple users. Not ideal as we want to have a single view called 'My Work' based on a few other filters. This is not a Case object nor are we using the owner field concept.

Comment: Is `Reviewer Assigned` a custom field? You could create a formula field to see if that field is equal to `$User.Id` and then leverage the formula field in the list view

Comment: Has this been ever solved? 
We face the same issue in experience cloud where the sharing set uses the contact field but the challenge is if a platform user creates a case, that user does not have a contact linked
So I need a listview showing only Where contact == user.contact OR created by == current user